# Are Chern classes well defined up to contractible choice?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, characteristic-classes

The Chern classes are, by definition, cohomology classes. And
cocycle representatives of the Chern classes are not unique.

But it might be the case that cocycle representatives of the Chern classes are **unique up to contractible choice**.

The following kind-of-answer is not what I'm looking for:
One obvious way to make Chern classes of vector bundles unique up to contractible choice is to pick, once and for all, cocycle representatives of the universal Chern classes $c_n\in H^{2n}(BU,\mathbb Z)$. But that's not a good answer, because this depends on making a choice of lifting someting in $H^{2n}(BU,\mathbb Z)$ to something in $Z^{2n}(BU,\mathbb Z)$. I don't want to have to make *any* arbitrary choices.

So, what I'm asking is:
 is there a **best** way to pick (up to contractible choice) a cocycle representative of the universal Chern classes $c_n\in H^{2n}(BU,\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be turned into a complete answer, but $c_1$ is completely determined as the map $BU\to BU_1=K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ given by the determinant homomorphism $U\to U_1$ (and the identification $BU_1=K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ is the same as the choice of a generator of $\pi_1U_1$, say pick a counterclockwise rotation :)). Then one can hope to describe $c_n$ in a similar way using symmetric polynomials in $c_1$...

Comment: Hmm. Can you choose a connection on the universal vector bundle and then define cocycle representatives via the curvature of the connection? So then these classes would be parametrized by the space of connections.

Comment: To talk about connections on the universal vector bundle we do have to pick a geometric representative of the underlying base homotopy type BU (maybe that’s ok though); if we are allowed to pick a representative of BU we can also choose the one with only even dimensional cells, where the lift from cohomology to cocycles is unique.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries. Your answer is good when working with real coefficients. But it doesn't settle the questions when working with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients.

Comment: Is there a "best" way to pick a cocycle representing a given orientation class of $S^1$?  I'd guess no, and moreover that the required choice is not contractible.

Comment: I guess that the concept of cocyles depends on the choice of your cohomology theory (singular, etc.).

Comment: To refine Chris Schommer-Pries's and Dmitri Pavlov's suggestions to cohomology with integer coefficients, perhaps we could use the fact that characteristic classes produced by Chern--Weil theory lift to Cheeger--Simons differential cohomology. (I know very little about this subject, so maybe this is not a helpful comment. Also, I see that @DmitriPavlov mentions $\mathrm{K}(\mathbb{Z},2k)$, so perhaps I am just rehashing their suggestion.)

Comment: The choice of an orientation gives a map of ring spectra $MU\to H\mathbb Z$, so that it suffices to produce Chern classes in complex cobordism. Maybe we could try to charakterize Chern classes from Thom classes. Then $MU$ has canonical Thom classes...

Comment: It seems to me that this splits into two pieces. I think producing a canonical first Chern cycle is not trivial. Having fixed that, I'm more optimistic about producing higher Chern classes from the first as symmetric polynomials. People have suggested several approaches, but I suggest that they should exist over $BNT$, of which $BG$ is a stable summand by the Becker-Gottlieb transfer.

Answer (score 11):

I think that the best approach is to use the construction in the 1993 paper "[Algebraic cycles and infinite loop spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01244311)", which I learned about from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/387074/10366) by Jeremy Hahn.  To explain the context, recall that people now mostly use orthogonal spectra as a setting for stable homotopy theory (if they have any concrete foundation at all).  One can compare orthogonal spectra with based spaces, but it is often more convenient to compare them with based orthogonal spaces, i.e. functors from $\mathcal{L}$ to based spaces, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the category of finite-dimensional real inner product spaces and linear isometric embeddings.  There is a Quillen equivalence from orthogonal spaces to spaces given by $X\mapsto\text{colim}_nX(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  This sends commutative monoids in based orthogonal spaces (which May used to call $\mathcal{J}_*$-functors) to infinite loop spaces.  There is also a unitary version of all this based on finite-dimensional complex vector spaces equipped with hermitian inner products.  The cited paper defines a morphism $c\colon P\to Q$ in the category of commutative monoids in based unitary spaces.  Here $P$ corresponds to $\mathbb{Z}\times BU$, and $Q$ corresponds to $\prod_nK(\mathbb{Z},2n)$ and $c$ corresponds to the total Chern class.  The definition of $Q$ involves Chow varieties, which involve formal $\mathbb{N}$-linear combinations of subvarieties of projective space.  The definition of $P$ involves linear subvarieties and $c$ is just an inclusion.

Comment: I guess, in your language, my question becomes whether $Q$ is defined in such a way that there is a canonical (up to contractible choice) projection map $Q\to K(\mathbb Z,2n)$, for every $n$...

Comment: I think that the proof implicitly gives a specific zigzag of equivalences joining $Q$ to any other reasonable model of the same homotopy type.  Given such a zigzag, there is a contractible space of choices of how to straighten it.

Answer (score 5):

Since the mapping space $map (BU(n);K(\mathbb{Z},2k))$ does not have contractible components, you need to make non-contractible choices somewhere. I understand Andre's question in the sense that you want as few choices as possible, and that the choices look more 'natural' than just picking cocycles for all Chern classes at random.

Here is an attempt for a construction for $\it{integral}$ coefficients. It does not quite work, but if you pass to $\it{rational}$ coefficients, the construction depends only on two noncontractible universal choices.

-(a) Fix an actual map $MU \to H \mathbb{Z}$ of spectra, implementing the Thom class of complex vector bundles.

-(b) Fix a cycle representing the generator of $H_2 (BU(1);\mathbb{Z})$ dual to $c_1 (L_1)$.

Choice (a) should give cocyle representatives for the Thom class of all of the universal bundles $L_n \to BU(n)$.

As for an arbitrary rank $n$ vector bundle $V \to X$, the space of bundle maps (fibrewise isomorphisms) $V \to L_n$ is contractible, the construction yields cocycle representatives for the Thom classes of arbitrary vector bundles, unique up to contractible choice once (a) is fixed.

Since the top Chern class $c_n (V)$ is given by pulling back the Thom class along the zero section, we obtain cocycle representatives for the top Chern class, unique up to contractible choice.

The lower Chern classes $c_k \in H^{2k}(BU(n);\mathbb{Z})$ can be defined by the following recipe: consider the external tensor product $L_n \boxtimes L_1 \to BU(n) \times BU(1)$. We can write
$$c_n (L_n \boxtimes L_1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} c_k (L_n) \boxtimes c_1 (L_1)^{n-k}
$$
using the Kuenneth formula. Using the slant product, we can rewrite this formula as
$$
c_k (L_n) := c_n (L_n \boxtimes L_1) / b_{n-k}
$$
where $b_{n-k} \in H_{2n-2k}(BU(1))$ is the homology class with $\langle c_1 (L_1)^{n-k},b_{n-k} \rangle =+1$.

To turn this into something on the chain level, observe that the slant product is defined on the (co)chain level, depending on the (contractible) choice of an Eilenberg-Zilber map. Furthermore, we need cycles representing $b_{n-k}$.

With rational coefficients, such cycles can be defined using only the choice a cycle representing $b_1$, since you can recover $b_{n-k}$ as the $n-k$-fold Pontrjagin product of $b_1$, divided by $\frac{1}{(n-k)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

In “Chern–Weil forms and abstract homotopy theory”, Freed and Hopkins compute the de Rham cohomology of $\def\B{{\sf B}}\B_∇ G$, the moduli stack (in groupoids) of principal $G$-bundles with connections on the site of smooth manifolds.

The de Rham cohomology of $\B_∇ G$ turns out to be isomorphic to the graded algebra of $G$-invariant polynomials (placed in even degrees) on the Lie algebra of $G$, with the zero differential.

This provides a completely canonical cocycle for Chern classes (taking $\def\U{{\rm U}} G=\U(n)$) as a morphism of stacks in groupoids on the site of smooth manifolds.  This canonical cocycle can be used to produce cocycles in other models.  For example, for a model using simplicial sets only, we can evaluate the above simplicial presheaves on smooth simplices $Δ^m$ and take the diagonal simplicial set, which yields a map of simplicial sets whose domain is weakly equivalent to $BG$ and the codomain is weakly equivalent to $\def\K{{\rm K}}\def\Z{{\bf Z}}\K(\Z,2k)$; the resulting simplicial map is a classifying map for the $k$th Chern class.

Comment: Your answer is no different from what CSP wrote in his comment. It works with real coefficients, but it doesn't settle the question when working with ℤ coefficients.